# Adding values to dictionary keys from a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following list and dictionary:

```
list = [[1,2,2],[2,3,3],[3,4,4]
dict = {1:[], 2:[], 3:[]}
```

Let's say I wanted to append all values that proceed dict[keys] into their respective keys such that:

```
dict = {1:[2,2], 2:[3,3], 3:[4,4]}
```

I've attempted using multiple loops to accomplish this.  However whenever I do that all values get searched and appended to each dict[key] simultaneously.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = [[1,2,2],[2,3,3],[3,4,4]]

# last key wins 
d = {sublist[0]:sublist[1:] for sublist in l}

print(d)
```

You construct the dictionary from your lists elements. Do not use `list` or `dict` as names, they shadow the built-ins.

`sublist[0]` is the first element, `sublist[1:]` are the rest of the elements of each item in l.

More about the syntax used here: [PEP 274: Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Outputs:

```
{1: [2, 2], 2: [3, 3], 3: [4, 4]}     # last key wins (no duplicates present)
```

---

If you need to merge as well, you can use:

```
# merging keys into values as list of sublists
l = [[2,2,2],[2,3,3],[3,4,4]]
d1 = {}
for sub in l:
    # creates dict of { key: [ [int,...], [int,...] ], ... } for same keys
    d1.setdefault(sub[0],[]).append(sub[1:])
```

or by flattening:

```
# merging keys into values as flattened list
d2 = {}
for sub in l:
    # creates dict of { key: [ int,...,int,... ], ... } for same keys
    d2.setdefault(sub[0],[]).extend(sub[1:])
```

Outputs:

```
{2: [[2, 2], [3, 3]], 3: [[4, 4]]}    # merging keys into values as list of sublists

{2: [2, 2, 3, 3], 3: [4, 4]}          # merging keys into values as flattened list
```

For merging I used [dict.setdefault()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) you might want to take a peek at [collections.defaultdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which I get assured is better suited.